# Grouping of values in Tableau

Tags: graph, charts, tableau-api

I have a a column with amount ranging from 0-500.
I need to group it into 3 sections 0-100,100-250 and 250 and above.
I need to showcase them in report using diff color.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can distinctly label the sections using a calculated field:

```
IF [FieldName] <= 100 THEN "Color 1"
ELSEIF [FieldName] <= 250 THEN "Color 2"
ELSE "Color 3"
END
```

From there, place the newly created calculated field onto the Color shelf and edit accordingly.

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please apply the green check/tick. If not please update here and I will continue to troubleshoot.